# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client error (11.2 installed on dev machine, 9.2 installed on target host machine)

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, oracle9i

I've have an ASP.NET application that I developed on a machine with Oracle 11.2 installed on it. It runs fine on local host but when I publish it to a server box with Oracle 9.2 installed on it I get the 'The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client' error. I was told that upgrading the version of Oracle on the remote server is not a possibility.I read a solution as downgrading the version of Oracle on my machine but I'd rather avoid that if possible. Is there another way to get around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a matter of copying oci.dll, oraociei11.dll & OraOps11w.dll into my bin folder.